# game logic for bingo in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am building a script to check a players bingo card against numbers choose at random. I thought I had sufficient logic until I tested. **How would i check to see if a solution is valid no matter the order?** below is the logic chunk out of my larger program.

```
        chosennumbers = ['B8', 'O69', 'I27', 'G56']

    jordonsboard = ['B8', 'I18', 'N38', 'G47', 'O66',
                    'B10', 'I27', 'N44', 'G53', 'O71',
                    'B3', 'I19', 'fre', 'G48', 'O67',
                    'B4', 'I25', 'N39', 'G56', 'O65',
                    'B9', 'I30', 'N34', 'G58', 'O69']
    hitnodes = [12]  # this list houses hits on your board added 12 because its a free space
    win = False
    iterator = 0
    for i in chosennumbers:
        if i in jordonsboard:
            hitnodes.append(iterator)
        iterator += 1

if 0 in hitnodes:
    if 6 in hitnodes:
        if 12 in hitnodes:
            if 18 in hitnodes:
                if 24 in hitnodes:
                    win = True
                    print('Bingo!')
    elif 2 in hitnodes:
        if 3 in hitnodes:
            if 4 in hitnodes:
                win = True
                print('Bingo!')
    elif 5 in hitnodes:
        if 10 in hitnodes:
            if 15 in hitnodes:
                if 20 in hitnodes:
                    win = True
                    print('Bingo!')
if 1 in hitnodes:
    if 6 in hitnodes:
        if 11 in hitnodes:
            if 16 in hitnodes:
                if 21 in hitnodes:
                    win = True
                    print('Bingo!')
if 2 in hitnodes:
    if 7 in hitnodes:
        if 12 in hitnodes:
            if 17 in hitnodes:
                if 22 in hitnodes:
                    win = True
                    print('Bingo!')
if 3 in hitnodes:
    if 8 in hitnodes:
        if 13 in hitnodes:
            if 18 in hitnodes:
                if 23 in hitnodes:
                    win = True
                    print('Bingo!')
if 4 in hitnodes:
    if 8 in hitnodes:
        if 16 in hitnodes:
            if 20 in hitnodes:
                win = True
                print('Bingo!')
    elif 9 in hitnodes:
        if 14 in hitnodes:
            if 19 in hitnodes:
                if 24 in hitnodes:
                    win = True
                    print('Bingo!')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `set.intersection()`. You can put all of your numbers within a set and check if its intersection with your list is equal with the set.

```
my_set = {0, 6, 12, 18, 24}

if my_set.intersection(hitnodes) == my_set:
    # do stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how i ended up doing it. Since i need to know if my hitlist matches every item in each solution this is how i built it.

```
> import urllib.request import urllib.parse import re import collections
> 
> url =
> 'http://www.executiveadministrator.com/cgi-local/inoutPROhosted4/inoutPRO.pl?refresh=1&ID=AFTCO'
> #testlist = ['B9,','B8,','B3,','B4,'] counter = 0 #inicialize counter hitlist = [] #inicialize hitlist
> 
> board = ['B8,', 'I18,', 'N38,', 'G47,', 'O66,',
>          'B10,','I27,', 'N44,', 'G53,', 'O71,',
>          'B3,', 'I19,', 'fre,', 'G48,', 'O67,',
>          'B4,', 'I25,', 'N39,', 'G56,', 'O65,',
>          'B9,', 'I30,', 'N34,', 'G58,', 'O69,']
> 
> resp = urllib.request.urlopen(url) #request html data from website
> respdata = resp.read() #store request data in respdata
> 
> string = '<TEXTAREA ROWS="2" NAME="1 ANNOUNCEMENTS-return" COLS="50"
> WRAP=VIRTUAL>(.*?)</TEXTAREA>'#search within text area for bingo
> numbers search = re.findall(string, str(respdata)) #find all between
> <b> and </b> searchstring = str(search) #convert search results to
> string and assign cleanlist = searchstring.split() #split seachstring
> to a cleaned up list cleanlist.append('fre,') #add free space
> solutions =
> [(0,6,12,18,24),(4,8,12,16,20),(0,5,10,15,20),(1,6,11,16,21),
>               (2,7,12,17,22),(3,8,13,18,23),(4,9,14,19,24),(0,1,2,3,4),
>                 (5,6,7,8,9),(10,11,12,13,14),(15,16,17,18,19),(20,21,22,23,24)]
> 
> for i in board: #for each item in board
>     for j in cleanlist: #and for each item in cleanlist
>         if i == j: #check to see if they match append match
>             hitlist.append(counter)#add hit number to hitlist
>             print('hit: {} at space: {}'.format(i, counter))
>     counter += 1
> #check each possible solution against current hit list for each in solutions: #for each item in solutions
>     if collections.Counter(hitlist) == collections.Counter(each): #check to see if all items match
>         print('BINGO')
```